# traverse over all of a label

Tags: java, label, neo4j

I'm using Neo4j 2.0 milestone 3.

Currently have this working code:

```
String DB_PATH = "/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/community-1.8.1-unix/libexec/data/graph.db";
GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);
Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
try {
  Node myNode = graphDb.createNode();
  Label myLabel = DynamicLabel.label('Label_Name');
  myNode.addLabel(myLabel);
  tx.success();
}
finally {
  tx.finish();
}
```

How would I use the embedded API to traverse over all nodes that have `Label_Name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out:

```
GlobalGraphOperations.at(graphDb).getAllNodesWithLabel(DynamicLabel.label('Label_Name'));
```

http://api.neo4j.org/current/org/neo4j/tooling/GlobalGraphOperations.html#getAllNodesWithLabel(org.neo4j.graphdb.Label)